# Windows Impersonation in an on-premises WCF Service using an Azure Service Bus Endpoint

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, impersonation, servicebus

I have a WebAPI based master web service which provides a list of Azure Service Bus Relay endpoints for on-premises WCF services based on the client who logged onto the Master Service via a WPF desktop App using ADAL Azure Active Directory logon. This works fine, and the master service returns a Service Bus endpoint for the client who logged in.

The client can then connect to the WCF on-premises service via the returned Service Bus endpoint no problem.

However there are certain methods in the on-premises WCF service which need to impersonate the calling client-user and this is where I am stuck. Does anyone know of a way to be able to impersonate a client who has called a WCF service via the Azure Service Bus relay?? I can't "log the user on" in order to impersonate them because I don't know their domain password, I only have available their logon UPN.

Comment: On your WCF you want to find out who is logged in as a CLIENT ?

Comment: I need the credentials of the client (user) running the app which called the WCF service so that I can impersonate them on certain service methods, but I can't use Windows Authentication on the WCF binding because it is published using the Azure service bus relay bindings which don't have an option for Windows Authentication (as far as I can tell). Maybe I need some sort of authentication header adding to the service request which would include the client's credentials, but so far I haven't been able to find an example of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can potentially solve this problem in the same way I did when writing a paper about flowing an identity through azure service bus queues.  You would need to have elevated priveledges for your service account running the on premise service which may introduce a vulnerability depending on how your solution works but if you can mitigate that then this approach would work.

The paper is on the following link:
Flowing a Windows Identity through Azure Service Bus Queues
http://microsoftintegration.guru/publications/whitepapers/

Hope this helps
Mike

Comment: thanks Mike - the solution in the end was to set up constrained delegation for the on premise service account for the downstream services which require impersonation, using the "any authentication protocol" option meaning we can impersonate even though we only have the upn of the account to be impersonated. Once the necessary SPNs were set up things worked swimmingly. I know more about Kerberos now than I cared to know before!